# Problem with rbind.zoo(...) : indexes overlap in lag function

Tags: r, lag, zoo

I have trouble with an error in zoo, using the lag.zoo function

Error in rbind.zoo(...) : indexes overlap
Warning: In zoo(rval[i], index(x)[i]) :
some methods for “zoo” objects do not work if the index entries in ‘order.by’ are not unique

```
t1<-c("21.04.2019 20:00:00","21.04.2019 20:01:00","21.04.2019 20:02:00","21.04.2019 20:03:00","21.04.2019 20:04:00","21.04.2019 20:05:00","21.04.2019 20:06:00","21.04.2019 20:07:00","21.04.2019 20:08:00","21.04.2019 20:09:00","21.04.2019 20:10:00","21.04.2019 20:11:00")

v1<-c(15,15,15,14,15,14,15,14,15,15,15,14)

z1<-zoo(v1, as.POSIXct(strptime((t1), "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S")))

head(lag(z1[,1], 2))
```

Using k=1 gives back the original time without lag (and no error and warning)

Comment: Try `head(stats::lag(z1[,1], 2))`, there are some 'genious' packages out there that mask the `lag` function.

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems:

- Perhaps dplyr is loaded.  It clobbers `lag` from the base of R so that no other packages can use it.  When you load dplyr do it like this:

  ```
  library(dplyr, exclude = c("lag", "filter"))
  ```

  If you need to use dplyr's `lag` then refer to it as `dplyr::lag` .   Although the above is probably the best way to handle this to avoid errors, if you already have dplyr loaded so that it is too late you can:

  1. detach it, `detach("package:dplyr", unload = TRUE)`, or
  2. use `stats::lag` to refer to the `lag` generic in the base R which in turn will dispatch `lag.zoo` since zoo works consistently with it or
  3. enter `lag <- stats::lag` and then use `lag` as usual and use `dplyr::lag` if you need that version.
- z1 is a vector zoo object, not a matrix zoo object so it does not really make sense to refer to its first column. It has no columns. Omit the `[, 1]` .
- you probably meant -2, not +2.  zoo uses the same convention as R itself which  is that a lag of 2 refers to lagging the index, not the data, by 2.  That is, a series lagged by 2 starts earlier whereas you likely want it to start later. See `?stats::lag` for more on this. For example, below with a negative lag the 1st lag starts one position later and the 2nd lag starts 2 positions later.

  ```
  stats::lag(z1, -(0:2))

  ##                     lag0 lag-1 lag-2
  ## 2019-04-21 20:00:00   15    NA    NA
  ## 2019-04-21 20:01:00   15    15    NA
  ## 2019-04-21 20:02:00   15    15    15
  ## 2019-04-21 20:03:00   14    15    15
  ## 2019-04-21 20:04:00   15    14    15
  ## 2019-04-21 20:05:00   14    15    14
  ## 2019-04-21 20:06:00   15    14    15
  ## 2019-04-21 20:07:00   14    15    14
  ## 2019-04-21 20:08:00   15    14    15
  ## 2019-04-21 20:09:00   15    15    14
  ## 2019-04-21 20:10:00   15    15    15
  ## 2019-04-21 20:11:00   14    15    15
  ```

Comment: that helped a lot !!